# assign numeric value of digit into char using scanf

Tags: c, char, scanf, return-value, c89

If I have a char: `char ch`

and i want to assign it a numeric value of a digit, for example, if the user enters 0, i want the char to have the value 0 (`'\0'`) and not 48 (`'0'`)

if i try `scanf("c", &ch)` it will assign `48` (ascii value for 0), and if i try `scanf("d", &ch)` i get an error.

I know it can be done by receiving it as string, and then converting it into char, and then using `ch-'0'` to get the numeric value, but is it possible without this extra steps?

Comment: Read the input into an `int`, then assign the `int` to the `char`.

Comment: @user3121023 do i need to use %hhd when I am using printf as well? or is %d ok?

Comment: @user3121023 I use C90 and it does not support hhd

Comment: @avivgood2: Stop using C 1990.

Comment: avivgood2, What compiler are you using?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica gcc

Comment: avivgood2, To access ability to use  `"%hhd"`, use gcc with a more recent standard like `gcc -std=c99` or `gcc -std=c11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> assign numeric value of digit into `char` using `scanf`

Since C99, the direct way is

```
char ch;
scanf("%hdd", &ch);
// or to insure reading only 1 character
scanf("%1hdd", &ch);
```

Before that, the below is common. [@Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61008325/assign-numeric-value-of-digit-into-char-using-scanf/61013849#comment107933659_61008325)

```
char ch;
int ch_int;
if (scanf("%d", &ch_int) == 1) {
  ch = ch_int;
```

---

Or read the `char` and convert from its character value to its numeric value.  (OP is already familiar with this)

```
char ch;
scanf("%c", &ch);
ch -= '0';
```